# When ant clean debug is run

Tags: android, git, shell, mobile, touch

Hi I am trying to create a android native app in salesforce touch platform. I am trying to copy lib from sample project to my app. 
1st i entered this commend in my cmd

```
cd $TARGET_DIR
$ANDROID_SDK_DIR/tools/android update project -p . -t 1
```

the result was 
     `Updated project.properties
     Updated local.properties
     Updated file C:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\build.xml
     Updated file C:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\proguard-project.txt
     It seems that there are sub-projects. If you want to update them
     please use the --subprojects parameter.`

after that i used this command

```
 ant clean debug
```

This time i get the result as

```
 l
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__auth_container
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idAuthContainer() { return R.id.sf__auth_container; }
 [javac]                                               ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:46: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__menu_clear_cookies
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idItemClearCookies() { return R.id.sf__menu_clear_cookies; }
 [javac]                                                  ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:47:  cannot  find symbol
  [javac] symbol  : variable sf__menu_pick_server
  [javac] location: class android.R.id
  [javac]     public int idItemPickServer() { return R.id.sf__menu_pick_server; }
  [javac]                                                ^
  [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:48: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__menu_reload
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idItemReload() { return R.id.sf__menu_reload; }
 [javac]                                            ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:49: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__load_separator
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idLoadSeparator() { return R.id.sf__load_separator; }
 [javac]                                               ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:50: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__load_spinner
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idLoadSpinner() { return R.id.sf__load_spinner; }
 [javac]                                             ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:51: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__server_name
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idServerName() { return R.id.sf__server_name; }
 [javac]                                            ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:52: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable Text_HostName
  [javac] location: class android.R.style
 [javac]     public int styleTextHostName() { return R.style.Text_HostName; }
 [javac]                                                    ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:53: cannot  find symbol 
 [javac] symbol  : variable Text_HostUrl
 [javac] location: class android.R.style
 [javac]     public int styleTextHostUrl() { return R.style.Text_HostUrl; }
 [javac]                                                   ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:55: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode
 [javac] location: class android.R.layout
 [javac]     public int layoutPasscode() {return R.layout.sf__passcode; }
 [javac]                                                 ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:56: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode_title
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idPasscodeTitle() {return R.id.sf__passcode_title; }
 [javac]                                              ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:57: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode_error
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idPasscodeError() {return R.id.sf__passcode_error; }
 [javac]                                              ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:58: cannot find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode_instructions
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idPasscodeInstructions() {return  R.id.sf__passcode_instructions; }
 [javac]                                                     ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:59: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode_text
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idPasscodeText() {return R.id.sf__passcode_text; }
 [javac]                                             ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:60: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode_create_title
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringPasscodeCreateTitle() {return  R.string.sf__passcode_create_title; }

 [javac]                                                            ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:61: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode_enter_title
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringPasscodeEnterTitle() {return  R.string.sf__passcode_enter_title; }
 [javac]                                                           ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:62: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode_confirm_title
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringPasscodeConfirmTitle() {return  R.string.sf__passcode_confirm_title;}
 [javac]                                                             ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:63: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode_enter_instructions
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringPasscodeEnterInstructions() {return  R.string.sf__passcode_enter_instructions; }
 [javac]                                                                  ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:64: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode_create_instructions
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringPasscodeCreateInstructions() {return  R.string.sf__passcode_create_instructions; }
 [javac]                                                                   ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:65: cannot  find symbol 
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode_confirm_instructions
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringPasscodeConfirmInstructions() {return  R.string.sf__passcode_confirm_instructions; }
 [javac]                                                                    ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:66: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode_min_length
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringPasscodeMinLength() {return  R.string.sf__passcode_min_length; }
 [javac]                                                          ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:67:cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode_try_again
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringPasscodeTryAgain() {return  R.string.sf__passcode_try_again; }
 [javac]                                                         ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:68: cannot find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcode_final
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringPasscodeFinal() {return R.string.sf__passcode_final; }
 [javac]                                                      ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:69: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__passcodes_dont_match
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringPasscodesDontMatch() {return  R.string.sf__passcodes_dont_match; }
 [javac]                                                           ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:71: cannot find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__picker_custom_label
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idPickerCustomLabel() {return R.id.sf__picker_custom_label; }
 [javac]                                                  ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:72: cannot find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__picker_custom_url
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idPickerCustomUrl() {return R.id.sf__picker_custom_url; }
 [javac]                                                ^
[javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:73: cannot  find symbol 
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__server_url_default_custom_label
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringServerUrlDefaultCustomLabel() {return  R.string.sf__server_url_default_custom_label;}
 [javac]                                                                    ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:74: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__server_url_default_custom_url
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringServerUrlDefaultCustomUrl() {return  R.string.sf__server_url_default_ custom_url;}
 [javac]                                                                  ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:75: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__server_url_add_title
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringServerUrlAddTitle() {return  R.string.sf__server_url_add_title;}
 [javac]                                                          ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:76: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__server_url_edit_title
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringServerUrlEditTitle() {return  R.string.sf__server_url_edit_title;}
 [javac]                                                           ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:77: cannot  find symbol 
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__custom_server_url
 [javac] location: class android.R.layout
 [javac]     public int layoutCustomServerUrl() {return  R.layout.sf__custom_server_url;  }
 [javac]                                                        ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:78: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__apply_button
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idApplyButton() {return R.id.sf__apply_button;}
 [javac]                                            ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:79: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__cancel_button
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idCancelButton() {return R.id.sf__cancel_button;}
 [javac]                                             ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:80: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__invalid_server_url
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringInvalidServerUrl() {return  R.string.sf__invalid_server_url;}
  [javac]                                                         ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:81: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__server_list_group
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idServerListGroup() {return R.id.sf__server_list_group; }
 [javac]                                                ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:82: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__server_picker
 [javac] location: class android.R.layout
 [javac]     public int layoutServerPicker() {return R.layout.sf__server_picker; }
 [javac]                                                     ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:83: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__auth_login_production
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringAuthLoginProduction() {return  R.string.sf__auth_login_production;}
 [javac]                                                            ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:84: cannot  find symbol 
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__auth_login_sandbox
 [javac] location: class android.R.string
 [javac]     public int stringAuthLoginSandbox() {return  R.string.sf__auth_login_sandbox;}
 [javac]                                                         ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:85: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__clear_custom_url
 [javac] location: class android.R.menu
 [javac]     public int menuClearCustomUrl() {return R.menu.sf__clear_custom_url; }
 [javac]                                                   ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:86: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__menu_clear_custom_url
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idMenuClearCustomUrl() {return R.id.sf__menu_clear_custom_url;}
 [javac]                                                   ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:87: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__edit_icon
 [javac] location: class android.R.drawable
 [javac]     public int drawableEditIcon() {return R.drawable.sf__edit_icon; }
 [javac]                                                     ^
[javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\SalesforceRImpl.java:88: cannot  find symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable sf__show_custom_url_edit
 [javac] location: class android.R.id
 [javac]     public int idShowCustomUrlEdit() {return R.id.sf__show_custom_url_edit;}
 [javac]                                                  ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\myappApp.java:39: method does  not override or implement a method from a supertype
 [javac]     @Override
 [javac]     ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\myappApp.java:46: cannot find  symbol
 [javac] symbol  : variable Encryptor
 [javac] location: class com.acme.mobileapp.myappApp
 [javac]             return Encryptor.hash(name + "x;lksalk1jsadihh23lia;lsdhasd2",   name + "112;k aslkxs0-12;skcxn1203ph");
 [javac]                    ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\myappApp.java:44: method does  not override or implement a method from a supertype
 [javac]     @Override
 [javac]     ^
 [javac] c:\Anu\SalesforceTouch\src\com\acme\mobileapp\myappApp.java:49: method does  not override or implement a method from a supertype
 [javac]     @Override
 [javac]     ^
 [javac] 78 errors
```

BUILD FAILED
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:680: The following error   occurred while executing this line:
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:693: Compile failed; see  the compiler error output for details.

does anybody know what might be the reason and please provide me the solution for this issue.